# Fazer elemento se expandir a partir do seu centro

Tags: css

O problema é: tenho uma `div` centralizada com aquele truque (trick) de container em `position: absolute` ou `fixed` e a `div` interna em `relative`.

Com podem ver, quando a animação é executada, a `div` interna (#square) cresce de cima para baixo. Eu gostaria que ela crescesse do seu centro e se expandisse para todos os lados, mas ela permanece na mesma distância do topo, por causa do `top: -30%`.  O que eu posso fazer para que, na animação, ela se expanda para todos os lados, ao invés de cima para baixo?

```js
// Função simples para animar a div com css transitions
var square = document.querySelector('#square');

setTimeout(function(){
      square.style.width = '100px';
      square.style.height = '100px';
}, 500);
```

```css
#container {
      position: fixed;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
}

#square {
      position: relative;
      left: -50%;
      top: -30%;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background: blue;
      transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" >
    <div id="square" > </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução simples é utilizar o `scale` em vez de modificar `width` e `height`:

```js
// Função simples para animar a div com css transitions
var square = document.querySelector('#square');

setTimeout(function(){
      square.style.transform = "scale(5)"; //scale em vez de width e height
      //scale(5) dá 5 vezes o tamanho, logo 100 por 100.
}, 500);
```

```css
#container {
      position: fixed;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
}

#square {
      position: relative;
      left: -50%;
      top: -30%;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background: blue;
      transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
      /*transform: scale(1); coloquei aqui para tornar claro que é o valor inicial, embora não seja necessário*/
}
```

```html
<div id="container" >
    <div id="square" > </div>
</div>
```

Para incorporar uma imagem no div será melhor fazer com que a transformação vá de um valor inferior a 0 até 1, para não distorcer. E definir a dimensão real da imagem no `width` e `height`.

Solução com imagem:

```js
// Função simples para animar a div com css transitions
var square = document.querySelector('#square');

setTimeout(function() {
    square.style.transform = "scale(1)"; //agora com 1 para ficar no tamanho real
}, 500);
```

```css
#container {
            position: fixed;
            left: 50%;
            top: 10%; /*passou a 10% aqui*/
        }
        
        #square {
            position: relative;
            left: -50%;
            top: 0;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Culmination200.jpg);
            transform:scale(0.1); /*tamanho começa mais pequeno para não distorcer*/
        }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="square"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Só tomar muito cuidado com o conteúdo da `div`. Se tiver algum texto, por exemplo, ele será aumentado junto.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Era mais ou menos isso que eu ia perguntar. Mas, no caso, é uma imagem. Não haveria distorção na imagem (se eu a inserisse já com o tamanho que ficaria depois da transição)?

Comment: Para uma imagem funciona bem, mas convém definir o url para o da imagem colocar os sizes corretos de acordo com a imagem e alterar a transformação de scale, de 0.x para 1